# Retrieving images loaded in the browser

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib2

The following code works great for fetching static images:

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve({SOME_URL}, "00000001.jpg")
```

I'd however like to fetch all media that I can load on WhatsApp Web. For instance, looking at the source of a conversation that's fully loaded on my screen, I can see the image URLs such as blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/a2e9249a-365c-4ce7-a3ce-795be018400e – that link/image can actually be opened in a separate browser tab.

If I replace {SOME_URL} with that link, Python doesn't recognise blob as a valid HTTP request. I have kept my browser with WhatsApp Web loaded in the background as I assume those links may actually change every time I load the conversation. But the first problem is trying to find a urlretrieve equivalent. Any thoughts? Thank you!

Comment: That link opens WhatsApp Web, depending on the cookies you're redirected. You can't hope to get something out of it.

Comment: Hmmm I would think that if I load a WhatsApp Web conversation in the browser, anything that's loaded up can technically be saved/downloaded. I'm not assuming to just run some code without pre-loading the conversation manually. Do you see what I mean?